# Trying to Update Elixir Phoenix Liveview to Version 0.18.16, Getting Strange Error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I am trying to update my liveview from v0.17.5 to v0.18.16. I put this in my mix.exs file:

```
{:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.18.16"},
{:floki, ">= 0.30.0", only: :test}
```

but I get error

```
Because your app depends on phoenix_live_view empty which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
```

Is this problem known and is there a workaround?

Comment: I cannot reproduce in a new mix project. Please provide your full mix.exs.

Comment: Just to be thorough, I would try deleting your `mix.lock`, your `deps/` and `_build/` directories and try `mix deps.get` again to verify that the issue persists.  One step further would be to remove the local hex cache (usually stored at `~/.hex/`).

Comment: @paulrusu, Can you send your entire mix.exs deps function? I suspect there could be a typo somewhere. That would give more insights into what could be the problem.

Comment: Is there maybe an issue with the fact that the project is still running elixir v. 1.12 ?

Answer (score 1):

Bumped upon a similar while manually upgrading Phoenix with

`{:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.18.16"},` switching to `{:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.19.0"}`.

The error for `mix deps.get` was:

```
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Resolution completed in 0.041s
Because "your app" depends on "phoenix_live_view empty" which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
** (Mix) Hex dependency resolution failed
```

Running `mix deps.tree` actually helped to see that one of my direct dependencies had `{:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.18.18"},` and after also upgrading it also to `0.19.0` the issue was gone.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar symptom when I upgrade phoenix_live_view from 0.17.5 to 0.18.16

```
$ mix deps.get
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Resolution completed in 0.105s
Because "the lock" depends on "phoenix_live_dashboard 0.6.5" which depends on "phoenix_live_view ~> 0.17.7", "the lock" requires "phoenix_live_view ~> 0.17.7".
And because "your app" depends on "the lock", "phoenix_live_view ~> 0.17.7" is required.
So, because "your app" depends on "phoenix_live_view ~> 0.18.16", version solving failed.
** (Mix) Hex dependency resolution failed
```

Remove `mix.lock`, run `mix clean` and `mix deps.get` would help to fix the issue.